# Word boundary doesn't work at end of non word character

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(ur'(?i)fizz\<buzz\>\b', u'fizz<buzz> - ANGLES', re.U)
[]

>>> re.findall(ur'(?i)fizz\<buzz\>', u'fizz<buzz> - ANGLES', re.U)
[u'fizz<buzz>']
```

The pattern must also match strings like `fizzbuzz` too, ie actual full word-only strings, but not inside other words. How can I accomplish this if `\b` after a non-word char isn't allowed?

Comment: `\b` IS allowed, but in your case, you don't have a word boundary after `>`.

Comment: Is end of line not a word boundary?

Comment: It may. A word boundary is a zero length assertion that match the "boundary" between a word character and a non word character.

Comment: If I add a space it still doesn't catch it. Ah, I mean it's allowed but doesn't match

Comment: It will match if you have a word character after `>`

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52004101/edit) and add some sample lines and expected result.

Comment: edited to show full example

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your pattern ends with a non-word-character you can use the non-word-boundary `\B`. If you can't be sure you can use the lookahead `(?!\w)` to make sure, that what follows is not a word character.